# Jquery not working properly with internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, struts2, struts

I have developed my page using struts2-jquery tabpannel. Everything is working well.

Functionality : I have data table on each tab, which submits data to action class and loads new data in ths same selected tab without refreshing the whole page.

Requirement : Whole page should not get reloaded. Just tabs should be refreshed/reload with new data

Problem : Working perfect with chrome browser, but not working properly in IE. In case of IE, on submiting my data in tabs, new data is successfully loaded in tab without refreshing the whole page. But soon after new data loaded, IE refresh the whole window.

**structure looks like : http://jsfiddle.net/rohanparekh/ZvtRM/7/**

I have tried both below methods to but no luck. Any idea ?

```
var e= document.getElementById("myForm");
        e.submit(); 
        $("#dashboardForm").submit();
```

Help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That jsfiddle link doesn't contain any forms or the code in question.

Comment: What is the action attribute on your form element?

Comment: Do you have an element with `id="submit"`?

Comment: <form id="dashboardForm"  action="someaction">. This is my action/form attribute. No id=submit element

Comment: here is the updated jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rohanparekh/ZvtRM/9/

my form is submitted from getApplicationValue() in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Add `type="button"` on html tag.. It will work if you choose IE7 from IE developer tools.

> A Submit button has the same default behavior as a button created by using the submit type with the input object. If the ENTER key is pressed while a user is viewing a form that contains a Submit button, the form is submitted. This default behavior of a Submit button is indicated by a border surrounding the button. The border appears when any control in the form receives the focus, other than another button. If the Submit button has a name property, the button contributes a name/value pair to the submitted data.
>
> Windows Internet Explorer 8 and later. The default value of this attribute depends on the current document compatibility mode. In IE8 Standards mode, the default value is submit. In other compatibility modes and earlier versions of Windows Internet Explorer, the default value is button.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534696(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for sharing but according to my requirement I dont have to use submit button